# make alias for svn repository

Tags: svn, alias

I am working with multiply repositories. 
Is it possible to create an alias for repositories. 
So I can use them instead of raw urls?

Namely instead of:

```
svn ls https://mysvnrepos.abs/trunk
```

I could use:

```
svn ls myrepo
```

Comment: It seems that you have to write alias for commands that used frequently.

Answer (score 7):

If you use Linux or Mac OS, you can define a global variable for your shell.

```
export myrepo="https://mysvnrepos.abs/trunk"
```

Then you can call

```
svn ls $myrepo
```

If you want to keep this variable, add the line above to your ~/.bashrc file (create it, if it does not exist).

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't believe there is.  In a standard Subversion workflow, it's quite rare to need to type the full URL -- most operations are on an already-checked-out working copy -- and in any case, if you're working with branches and tags, the URL would change between invocations.

That's not to say that the idea isn't any use, just that it's not useful enough for the developers to have added it.

If, like me, you have difficulty remembering what the URL was for a working copy you want to work with, `svn info` will give it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but maybe [externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) is what you're after.