# Concise command line for subversion copy (branch)

Tags: svn, command-line, copy, branch, command-line-arguments

All examples of svn branching I have seen so far look like this

`svn cp -m 'Making test branch' svn://svnrepo/hellosite svn://svnrepo/hellosite2`

So in order to branch I need to specify full URL of remote repository every time. But:

- Working copy is associated with one single remote repository. Even svn switch is considered to be advanced "surgical" operation.
- Branching of remote urls in same repository as working copy is always the case (at least I have never needed to branch in repository that is completely unrelated to current one).
- Copying between repositories is not supported (right?).
- Information about remote repository is available: see svn info.

So why in the world should I type complete URLs every time?!! Or do I miss something?
Is there some shortcut that allows referring current remote repository? Something like

`svn cp -m 'Making test branch' //hellosite //hellosite2`

Comment: Maybe git spoiled me already...

Comment: You can make an alias: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819343/make-alias-for-svn-repository/3966311#3966311

Comment: Thanks, that pretty close to what I need.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Using SVN 1.6 or later, if you're inside a working copy at the time then you can use the [caret notation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.advanced.reposurls) as a short-cut to the repository root, e.g.

```
svn cp -m 'Making test branch' ^/trunk ^/branches/hellosite
```

Note that on Windows at least you'll need to surround the `^/trunk` in double quotes to get it through the shell.

```
svn cp -m "Making test branch" "^/trunk" "^/branches/hellosite"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add an alias to your shell. See this [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819343/make-alias-for-svn-repository/3966311#3966311) for example.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a small bash alias file for convenient svn branching on the shell. (You can get the full file here: https://github.com/grexi/snippets/blob/master/svnaliases)

```
function getrepo {
    REPO=`LANG=C svn info | grep "Repository Root"`
    echo ${REPO:17}
}

function getrepobase {
   if [ "`LANG=C svn info | grep -c Relative`" -gt 0 ]; 
   then
      parent=".."
      grandparent=".."
      if [ -d ".svn" ]; then
          echo ""
      else
          while [ ! -d "$grandparent/.svn" ]; do
              parent=$grandparent
              grandparent="$parent/.."
          done
          echo $grandparent
     fi
   else
      parent=""
      grandparent="."
      while [ -d "$grandparent/.svn" ]; do
          parent=$grandparent
          grandparent="$parent/.."
      done
      echo $parent
   fi
}

function _svnbr {
    if [ $# != 2 ]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 branchname \"commit message\""
    else
        REPO=$(getrepo)
        if [ -z "$REPO" ]; then
            echo "You are not inside a svn working copy"
            return;
        fi
        svn copy $REPO/trunk $REPO/branches/$1 -m "$2"
        svn switch $REPO/branches/$1 $(getrepobase)
    fi
}
alias svnbr=_svnbr
```

Creating a branch now turns into

```
svnbr "branchname" "commit message"
```

inside your working directory.

Comment: Starting with SVN 1.8, the above approach won't work (since SVN now uses a single .svn subdirectory). The linked-to GitHub repo contains an updated version of the script that handles this, though.

Comment: // , Is this still current?

Answer (score -4):

This is one of the many weird SVN-isms that you will need to get used to.

Your assumption that you need to specify the full URL in both arguments is absolutely correct.